# VSCode Extension: No handler found for the command: 'sd.edit'

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension, and can happily test it in the debugger! However, after I package the extension up and install it manually, it gives me an error when I try to run commands:

> No handler found for the command: 'sd.edit' (or other applicable command, sd.edit is the one I tested for this)

Here is my `extension.ts`:

```ts
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode'; 
import * as sd from './sd';
import * as fileutil from './fileutil';
import * as indicator from './sdIndicator';

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let sdIndicator = new indicator.SdIndicator();
    context.subscriptions.push(sdIndicator); 

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    var editCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('sd.edit', () => {
        let sdWrapper = new sd.SdWrapper();
        sdWrapper.Edit(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName);
        sdIndicator.UpdateStatusBar();
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(editCommand);

    var sdRevert = vscode.commands.registerCommand('sd.revert', () => {
        let sdWrapper = new sd.SdWrapper();
        sdWrapper.Revert(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName);
        sdIndicator.UpdateStatusBar();
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(sdRevert);
}
```

and the `package.json` that defines commands:

```json
{
    "name": "vscode-sd",
    "displayName": "sd",
    "description": "SD integration with vscode",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "ryzngard",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^0.10.1"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "*"
    ],
    "main": "./out/src/extension",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "sd.edit",
                "title": "SD Edit File"
            },
            {
                "command": "sd.revert",
                "title": "SD Revert File"
            }]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/compile",
        "compile": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/compile -watch -p ./"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^1.6.2",
        "vscode": "0.10.x"
    }
}
```

Nothing looked out of place for me, and the fact that it works by debugging the extension seems odd. What's a way to debug an installed extension? Are there other things I should look for?

I tried adding `console.log` output as well in the activate function, but I don't know where that goes either.

Comment: I started another extension fresh, and added what I thought was parity to this and it works fine. I'm guessing there's a small typo I missed somewhere in the package.json or extension.ts

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the problem was.  It worked during debugging but didn't after packaging and installing.  To be a bit clearer, if I packaged on my dev box, installing would work as expected but if my CI machine (VSTS) built it, it wouldn't.

It turns out that the size of the created VSIX file was an order of magnitude different.  This was due to the fact that the number of node_modules in the VSIX varied greatly!  After investigating, it turns out that the difference between npm2 and npm3 caused the issue.  npm2 (which is what VSTS does today) packages up the npm modules differently than npm3 (and apparently it's incompatible with VS Code).

Comment: Interesting! That could have been the issue, but I'm not sure since I don't have the old project lying around anymore. That's good to know for future debugging though!